# Inner Join Two Datatable using Linq without having relation with another table

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, datatable

I want to put join on two `datatable` like

```
select * from table1 Inner join table2 on table2.id in (1,2,3)
```

Note: there is no relation like table1.id= table2.id

I have `Linq` code but don't know how to put such `condition` please help

```
var JoinResult = (from p in table1 .AsEnumerable()
                              join t in table2 .AsEnumerable()
                              on p.Field<int>("id") equals t.Field<int>("id") 
                              select new
                              {
                                  ID = p.Field<int>("ID")                                     

                              }).ToList();
```

I dont have `on table1.id= table2.id` relation as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
select * from table1 Inner join table2 on table2.id in (1,2,3)
```

technically speaking, `table2.id in (1,2,3)` is just a filter (`where`), and there is no `Inner Join`, but [Cross Join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), i.e. no join (relation) between the tables, but Cartesian product of the two.

So it really is something like this

```
select * from table1, table2 where table2.id in (1,2,3)
```

hence translating it to LINQ could be like this

```
var t2Filter = new HasSet<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3});
var result = (
    from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
    from t2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
    where t2Filter.Contains(t2.Field<int>("id"))
    select new
    {
        ID = t1.Field<int>("ID")
        // ...
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ivan but while dubugging at the tip of result it showing `result = Count = 0` and after converting it to `DataTable`, DataTable becomes blank, I think we are so close to my output just because of your answer

Comment: LINQ method is fine, have you checked the data, e.g. if table2 contains records with id 1,2 or 3, and table1 contains any records? Or post some sample data presenting the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you generate linq classes from db you will be able to do it like this:

```
var JoinResult = from t1 in _context.table1
            join t2 in _context.table2 on t1.id equals t2.id
            select new 
            { 
               Id = t1.id
            };
```

Where `_context` - is your Database.

By default **all joins in LinQ is inner**.

Don't use `.AsEnumerable()` if you using **LinqToSQL**. This basically will populate whole table from DB to your memory.

Comment: Thanx for your reply but i told you I dont have relation between `table 1.id=table 2.id`

Comment: @Dipesh that doesn't metter. If you will have that relation You will be able to do it without plain `join` in LinQ query. Just with navigation property (But at the background LinQ will translate it to Join). The only thing that you should care about - column type of `id` should be same in each table.

Comment: when i dont use .AsEnumerable it giving me a error Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DataTable'. 'Joint' not found.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relationship between the tables, you don't need any join.

You can use this.

```
            var Result = (from p in table1 .AsEnumerable()
                          from t in table2 .AsEnumerable()
                          where (t.id==1 || t.id==2)
                          select new
                          {
                              //whatever data you want.
                              ID = p.Field<int>("ID")                                     

                          }).ToList();
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can `contains`. Pls try this:

```
        selectList={1,2,3}//type of list (List<int>)

        var JoinResult = (from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                      from t2 in table2.AsEnumerable
                      where (t2 => selectList.Contains(t2.id))
                      select new
                      {      
                          //what if you want take here
                          ID = p.Field<int>("ID")                                     

                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: why do i need to` .AsEnumerable()? ` I've two datatables with data loaded from `different dB `I just want to put this join

Comment: when i dont use .AsEnumerable it giving me a error `Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DataTable'.  'SelectMany' not found.`

Comment: Really do you have two dB? Yeah bro then you must to use .AsEnumarable(). Because you must get data in memory from database. Did you solve this problem ?